# jwplayer 7.0.3 display play button when paused

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I would like to display the play button when the stream is on pause state.

So far I tried adding the jw-state-idle, but this removes the static image when paused.

Comment: Can you share your code to find the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some CSS to do this.

```
<style>
.jwplayer.jw-state-paused .jw-display-icon-container {
display: table;
}
.jwplayer.jw-state-paused .jw-icon-display::before {
content: "\e60e";
}
</style>
```

Comment: Awesome, no problem! We are thinking of making this a config option in a future release as well!